# Does Zarr has built-in multi-threading support for fast read and write?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, zarr

I am trying to speed up reading and writing Zarr files using multi-threading. For example, if I can store an array in 5 chunks, is there a way to use a thread per chunk to speed up reading and writing the array to and from disk (possibly using ThreadSynchronizer() and synchronizer argument?). I just want to speed up read/write. I don't want to parallelize the computation. I know that can be done with dask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Zarr has not, but dask has. So you can dome something like this.

```py
import dask.array as da

zarr_url = "s3://somewhere..."

x = da.from_zarr(zarr_url).compute()
```

Answer (score -1):

Zarr supports parallel reads and writes to different chunks without any additional synchronization, [see documentation](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#parallel-computing-and-synchronization). As pointed by the documentation, the bottleneck may be the GIL, in which case using multiple processes (rather than threads) can help speedup the processing.